# Create new array with values from other array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array containing individual arrays (pulled from db) with content similar to this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2014-11
        [time] => 2135
        [name] => John
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2014-11
        [time] => 5496
        [name] => Adam
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2014-12
        [time] => 1526
        [name] => John
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2014-12
        [time] => 5481
        [name] => Adam
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2014-12
        [time] => 3476
        [name] => Lizzie
    )
)
```

What I would like to do is to build up a new multi dimensional array based on the previous array, where array's with the same month are joined together in the following way:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2014-11
        [John] => 2135
        [Adam] => 5496
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2014-12
        [John] => 1526
        [Adam] => 5481
        [Lizzie] => 3476
    )
)
```

I have tried to look at various array functions, but simply can't get my around on how to achieve this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into the following snippet.

```php
$output = array(); // Where the output will be saved

foreach ($input as $row) { // Need to process the original input array

    $date = $row['date']; // Grouping by the date value, thus we use it as an index in an associative array

    if (empty($output[$date])) {
        $output[$date] = array('date' => $date); // Make sure the 'date' value is in the final output
    }

    $output[$date][$row['name']] = $row['time']; // Actual values, e.g., [Adam] => 5496
} 

$output = array_values($output); // Removing original indexes from the associative array
```

The desired array structure in the question is kinda strange but no question asked.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestion! It works as advertised.

The reason that I want the array like that is because the data is going to be used for a stacked bar chart, and as I see it this would be the best format to feed to the Google API.

I'm definitely very open other suggestions if any. I'm by far a very noob PHP developer, which probably also is mirrored in my way of thinking :-)